# Render entity with twig

Tags: theming, 8, entities, paragraphs

I am using Drupal 8.

I have a content type of Browse that has a bunch of paragraphs that can be inserted into each field_region. Inside field_region_iv_d I have a reference entity field that just references the Blog content type. So when creating the Browse Content you can click on the field_region_iv_d field and then select add blog and you just start typing the title of the blog and it auto completes.

So now on the actual Browse page if you are viewing the page. Where the region_iv_d is supposed to display I need all of the referenced blogs to display in this spot. I can not for the life of me figure out how to get this to display. I could possibly have this setup wrong. Maybe I need to use a twig field template? Maybe I need to add some special preprocessor code? I have tried a ton of different preprocessor code and was unable to get this results that I am looking for.

Here is general view of my setup.

content type = Blog

content type = Browse
|___ field: Region D  - field_region_iv_d - Entity reference revisions

Paragraph Type = 'Blog Block - blog_block
|**_ field: Blog Reference - field_blog_reference - Entity reference

|_** Manage Display: Blog Reference - (Label)Above - (Format)Rendered Entity

Twig Template: paragraph-blog-block.html.twig

Comment: Shouldn't the twig template name be **paragraph--blog-block.html.twig**?

Comment: Also what theme are you using, and post your custom twig template code if you have any. Simply outputting `{{ content }}` or `{{ content.field_blog_reference }}` should iterate over each field delta and render its contents according to your formatter setting. I have done this same thing on a project I am working on and it works just fine... so there has to be some culprit. The default paragraph.html.twig that comes with Paragraphs would do this automatically unless you have an override.

Comment: Yes, it shows template name at bottom. That should be correct. paragraph--blog-block.html.twig.  I think my problem is that field_region_iv_d is an entity reference that references the paragraph entity reference that references the blog entity. So its multi layered entity reference. Think this could be some of my problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be, I am doing the same thing.

Comment: {{ content.field_blog_reference }} displays only the title. It doesn't give me any of the field values.

Comment: I suspect something else going on then... it should definitely render the entity.

Comment: This should just work out of the box. Are you sure you configured the right view mode and so on? Can you incloude a screenshot of the manage display screen (make sure the local tasks at the top are visible) as well a manage display screenshot of the browse node type. oh and same for the blog node type